# Proof By Induction: Fibonacci Results

Tags: proof-writing, induction, recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

Let say that the Fibonacci numbers are defined recursively by

```
F_0 = 0
F_1 = 1
F_(n+1) = F_n + F_(n-1), n >= 1
```

and the Fibonacci words are defined by the recurrence relation

```
f_0 = a
f_1 = ab
f_(n+1) = f_n f_(n-1)
```

Then, how would I prove the following results by induction?

```
|f_n| = F_(n+2)
```

This is what I have done so far. I have shown that the basis step is true for the value of n = 2 and declared an inductive hypothesis. However, from there I am not sure how I would prove the result in the inductive step. I know that i would have to prove that it would be true for any value k+1 where n = k+1, but from there, I am having trouble showing it.

```
 BASIS:
 Let’s assume n = 2 and f(n) = f(n-1) * f(n-2) and f(1) = ab,  f(0) = a then;
    f(n):
    |f(2)| = |f(1) * f(0)|
           = |ab * a|
           = |3|

    f(n+2):
    |f(4)| = |f(3) + f(2)|
           = |f(2) + f(1) + f(2) |
           = |f(1) + f(0) + f(1) + f(1) + f(0) + f(0) | 
           = |1 + 0 + 1 + 1 + 0|
           = |3|

    Therefore, f(n) = f(n+2) is true

    INDUCTIVE HYPOTHESIS:  Suppose |f(n)| = f(n+2) for all value of n >= 0.
```

Comment: Just use the fact that $|f(n+1)|=|f(n)+|f(n-1)|$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott how would i do that?

Comment: Your induction hypothesis tells you what $|f(n)|$ and $|f(n-1)|$ are; what are they?

Comment: well , |f(n)| = f(n+2) so |f(n-1)| = f(n+1)? So then |f(n+3)| = f(n+2) + f(n+1) right? but then what?

Comment: Not quite. First, let me correct the notation to use subscripts, since that’s how the notation was actually defined. Then $|f_n|=F_{n+2}$ and $|f_{n-1}|=F_{n-1}$: the $f_k$ are the words, and the $F_k$ are the numbers. Now what do you know about $F_{n+2}+F_{n+1}$? Use the definition of the Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: im not entirely sure. Wouldn't F_{n+2}+F_{n+1} = F_{n+3}?

Comment: Yes! And that’s exactly what you want.

Comment: ok, but im not sure i understand how that proves that |f_n| = F_(n+2)

Comment: It doesn’t: the induction step proves that **if** $|f_n|=F_{n+2}$ and $|f_{n-1}|=F_{n+1}$, **then** $|f_{n+1}|=F_{n+3}$. In other words, if the formula $|f_k|=F_{k+2}$ holds for $k=n$ and $k=n-1$, then it holds for $k=n+1$. Since we know that it holds for $k=0$ and $k=1$, we can conclude that it holds for all $k\ge 0$.

Comment: Ah i see, ok thanks!

Comment: You’re welcome!